# Jenkins downloads nuget packages from nuget.org even though I have removed the feed from NuGet.config

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, nuget

I have a internally hosted nexus for nuget packages. I have added the nexus repo url in nuget.config. Also I have removed the nuget.org feed, so it doesn't download packages from internet.
I have hosted jenkins in the same machine. But when performing build in jenkins, the nuget packages are getting downloaded from the internet instead of nexus repo. Does jenkins refer any separate nuget.config file? Or is there any command to remove the nuget.org feed, so that I can execute it in jenkins!

Comment: Can you show your build step please?

Comment: There is nothing much in the build step. Just ```dotnet build```. How I assured that the packages were getting downloaded from the internet is, if I did ```nuget list``` from the host machine command prompt, it lists only the packages in my nuget-hosted repo. If I did the same in jenkins execute windows batch, it lists all the packages available in internet which goes non-stop.

Answer (score 1):

As described by NuGet's docs on [Common NuGet configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior), NuGet accumulates settings from multiple `nuget.config` files. You didn't explain how you "removed the nuget.org feed", but there's only one way I can think of that makes it reliable and reproducible. As mentioned in both the docs page I already linked, and also the [nuget.config reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#package-source-sections), there's a `<clear />` element allowed inside the `<packageSources>` element which tells NuGet to ignore any source defined in any accumulated `nuget.config` file.

If you removed the nuget.org feed using Visual Studio, unfortunately VS's NuGet settings is far too simplistic to understand and handle the multi-file inherited settings. When adding or removing sources in VS, it typically edits your user-profile `nuget.config`, meaning it affects all solutions on the current machine, and current user profile. This means when you use the repo on a different machine, or even a different user-profile on the same machine, the NuGet settings you thought you applied to the solution are no longer there. You need to use nuget.exe, the dotnet cli, or just hand edit a nuget.config xml file.

NuGet will, on any machine it runs on and does not find a `nuget.config` file at the default user-profile location, create a `nuget.config` with `nuget.org` pre-configured. Therefore, if your repo does not explicitly clear inherited sources, when nuget runs for the first time on a new user-profile, it will create a `nuget.config` that includes `nuget.org`. Hence if your solution doesn't have its own nuget.config that uses `<clear />`, then it will inherit nuget.org on any machine you didn't remove nuget.org from the user profile nuget.config.

So, assuming the only setting needed is the company nuget feed, you should check in a `nuget.config` in your repo root with contents roughly similar to:

```xml
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="company-feed" value="https://wheverver/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I removed the nuget.org feed by just removing the following line from ```%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config```: ```<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />```. Is this the right way to remove the feed??

Comment: As you have highlighted, Jenkins is running in a different userprofile. So it ends up creating a new nuget.config, which gets the nuget.org feed by default.

Comment: One thing to note from that article: “...neither NugetDefaults.config nor any other mechanism in NuGetcan prevent access to package sources like nuget.org. If an organization wishes to block such access, it must use other means such as firewalls to do so.”

Comment: or create a `nuget.config` file next to your solution, and use `<clear />` like my answer described.

Comment: I wasn’t saying that to counteract what you said. I was just highlighting that you can’t block access to a source via NuGet. May have been a little off-topic, but I felt it was noteworthy. :)

Comment: you can block the source in your project using `<clear />`. The docs you mentioned are saying that even if you create a `NuGetDefaults.config` that does not use nuget.org, a solution that has its own nuget.config that uses nuget.org is still going to use nuget.org. `NuGetDefaults.config` cannot remove sources defined in a solution nuget.config.

Comment: I know. That’s what I was highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Run dotnet build with the `—source` ( or `-s`) option. This will allow you to specify the NuGet source. See [dotnet build docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) for more details.